# Android: Layout goes the default state when typing starts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-scrollview

I've been stuck on this issue for quite some time. In my application I have around 5 TextView's, when I press on the textview the SoftKeyboard comes up the layout get's shifted up to a position where I am able to see the TextView. But the problem is that when I start typing the layout comes back to normal and I am not able to see the textView

Here is what I wrote

```
        paramMarksTV.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        paramMarksTV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final View activityRootView =findViewById(R.id.headerpageLayout);
                activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        Rect rect = new Rect();
                        activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to mess with ViewTreeObserver. All you need is select [appropriate](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) value  for `android:windowSoftInputMode` in your AndroidManifest.xml for desired Activity.

Comment: I did tried with that in the beginning. Did not seem to work, that is why I had to go all the way to ViewTreeObserver

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. This is the layout file

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RLEvaluateButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="88dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVEvaluateE"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="@drawable/e_button" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVEvaluateVG"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="@drawable/vg_button" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVEvaluateG"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="@drawable/g_button" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVEvaluateF"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="@drawable/f_button" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVEvaluateNI"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:background="@drawable/ni_button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TVMarksEval"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="65dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="3dip"
        android:layout_height="88dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ETEvaluateComment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="78dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TVEvaluateparameter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The manifest file is quite long, so here is the part where I have declared the class

```
<activity
            android:name="com.newrubric.pep.android.ui.evaluate.NREvaluateActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
```